# Eclipse package does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a problem with imports in Eclipse. I have following exceptions:

```
[ERROR] .../ctc/wstx/io/ReaderSource.java:[9,24] package com.ctc.wstx.api does not exist
[ERROR] .../ctc/wstx/io/ReaderSource.java:[10,24] package com.ctc.wstx.exc does not exist
```

I use Maven, and I think I have the correct dependencies. In Maven the depedencies exist in the correct jar:

```
woodstox-core-asl-4.1.1.jar
  - com.ctc.wstx.api
     - CommonConfig.class
     - EmptyElementHandler.class
     - InvalidCharHandler.class
     - ReaderConfig.class
     - ValidatorConfig.class
     - WriterConfig.class
     - WstxInputProperties.class
     - WstxOutputProperties.class
```

---

```
com.ctc.wstx.exc
```

also exists. If I remove imports I can use Eclipse (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>) to import, so Eclipse sees that jar. Why do I have this problem? And how I can resolve this?

Comment: Which Maven scope has the `woodstox-core-asl-4.1.1.jar` (please show your `pom.xml`)? What is exactly in `.../ctc/wstx/io/ReaderSource.java` line 9 and 10?

Comment: Okay, it works... woodstox was added by cxf-api. If I added separately woodstox (created separately depedency) it started to work. Maybe someone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of your package  and  output file,I have met this problem past, it probably be resolved in the menu of configure buid path